# How to access solution items? c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Given the image below:

[image]

How can I access the `Queries.resx`?

Here is what's inside the .resx file. I want to get the value.
[image]

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Express (which doesn't support solution folders)? Otherwise what happens when you double-click the file?

Comment: Double-click on it?  Right click and choose "Open With..."?

Comment: Maybe you notes that the files are in your program solution folder on windows?  So you have to access to the map where you can find your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create a ResXResourceReader for the file items.resx.
ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(@"C:\Resource1.resx");

// Create an IDictionaryEnumerator to iterate through the resources.
IDictionaryEnumerator id = rsxr.GetEnumerator();

// Iterate through the resources and display the contents
foreach (DictionaryEntry d in rsxr)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}  Value: {1}",     
                              d.Key.ToString(),d.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: How you figured out what he was really asking is beyond me.  Great job!  +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think those resources get packaged up into the final assembly.

Solution items should only really be used for these types of files

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ee8zw5t.aspx

The standard visual studio Add Item screen does not let you add resource files directly to the solution.

[image]